# Is it possible to sniff a running python code?

Tags: python, security, smtp, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying send emails through SMTP securely. I have a framework that does not have any library for SMTP so I would like to call a python script with smtplib. However, I'm worried about credentials being exposed.

If I pass credentials as arguments to a python script, can someone that have physical access to the computer sniff the python call?

I'm running on Raspberry OS (linux).

Comment: Yes, command arguments are visible via `ps` and in `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

Comment: Physical security is required for a normal function of any computer system, because physical access gives a malicious person almost unlimited possibilities. For practical purposes you should care about access from other regular users on a multi-user system. As commented by @hmm, command arguments are not hidden. Use environment variables instead.